# RijndaelManaged - Padding нулями

Tags: c#, aes

```
using var aes = new RijndaelManaged
{
   KeySize = ...,
   BlockSize = ...,
   Key = ...,
   IV = ...,
   Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
   Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros // Вот это заполняет нулями
};
```

После расшифровки в конце файла появляется `NUL`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь знает как это фиксится?
Как их убрать?

Comment: `RijndaelManaged` устарел и содержит уязвимости, используйте `= Aes.Create()`. Покажите код полностью, которым вы тестируете работу.

Comment: result = result.Trim('\0');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RijndaelManaged, как и другие алгоритмы шифрования, работает блоками. Если данные не кратны размеру блока - конец добивается выбранным способом паддинга.

Если вы выбираете PaddingMode.Zeros - то исходные данные перед шифрованием добиваются нулями до кратности размеру блока. При расшифровке невозможно узнать, были ли там эти нули изначально, или были добавлены в качестве паддинга.

Если хотите автоматическое удаление паддинга - выберите что-нибудь другое вместо PaddingMode.Zeros - например, PaddingMode.PKCS7. Он добивает байтами со значением равному размеру добавленного паддинга - и это позволяет автоматически удалить добавленные байты при расшифровке.